# Auto Face Tagging Library

Tags: photo-tagging

I am looking for library which can auto tag persons on a photo. The features is similar to Facebook, Picasa or iPhoto tagging function. Preferably it's able to run on Linux server, callable through PHP and Python. Any recommendation? Thanks.

Comment: Kilk and Face.com API seems perfect for this. But it is closed after Facebook bought it. Any good alternative? Either open source or commercial.

Comment: Find a related question on Quora. http://www.quora.com/What-are-alternatives-to-Face-com

Answer (score 2):

With regard to what you're looking for, you probably aren't going to find anything that you can host on your own server. Rather, most companies will offer an API to which you can send requests, and you will be charged base don how much you use the API. In no particular order, here are several resources you might consider using.

1. https://lambdal.com/face-recognition-api - They have low priced entry options, and they are well-suited to detecting and recognizing new faces.
2. http://www.alchemyapi.com/products/alchemyvision/face-detection - This is more geared to recognizing famous or well-know people.

Comment: Hi altblahblah, thanks for the lead. Found a post online "Following Facebook’s Shut Down Of Face.com’s Facial Recognition API, Lambda Labs Debuts An Open Source Alternative" http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/04/following-facebooks-shut-down-of-face-coms-facial-recognition-api-lambda-labs-debuts-an-open-source-alternative/. Will take a look on it.